# Using "Bend Left" with the \draw commands causes a "Dimension Too Large" error

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cell}{256}

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (\cell,\cell);
\foreach \i in {0,8,...,\cell} {
\draw[thick,blue!50] (0,\i) -- (\cell,\i);
\draw[thick,blue!50] (\i,0) -- (\i,\cell);
}

\draw[line width=20pt] (10,10) to (246,10) to (246,246) to[bend left] (10,246) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
<recently read> \pgf@xa

l.25 ...46,10) to (246,246) to[bend left] (10,246)
                                               -- cycle;
?
```

When I removed `[bend left]` the error goes away. Strangely, if I just press `enter` when confronted with the error, the code compiles correctly. However, I can't figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself is missing from your question, but it is essentially self-explanatory: you've asked TeX to handle a dimension in excess of the maximum it can deal with - about 19'.

The confusing part is that although your diagram is enormous (more than 2.5m by 2.5m), it does not seem to be *that* big.

The issue is that to draw the curve, TeX has to perform some calculations. These calculations involve a dimension in excess of the maximum, even though the dimensions of the final image do not.

When you ignore the error. the code compiles but not correctly. To compile correctly, it would need to produce the output you'd expect if TeX had no maximum dimension of if its maximum exceeded the largest size required to perform your calculation. That's not possible, so it tries to get as close as it can. The result is a curved line but not exactly the curve requested.

Here's a modified example with somewhat saner dimensions:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cell}{10}

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (\cell,\cell);
\foreach \i in {0,8,...,\cell} {
\draw[thick,blue!50] (0,\i) -- (\cell,\i);
\draw[thick,blue!50] (\i,0) -- (\i,\cell);
}

\draw[line width=2pt] (.1,.1) to (9.9,.1) to (9.9,9.9) to[bend left] (.1,9.9) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This compiles without error to produce the following.

[image: working example]

To see that the result from your code is not really correct, we can extend the example to show how the curve changes as the dimensions increase.

[image: curve variation with increased dimensions]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cell}{20}

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (\cell,\cell);
\foreach \i in {0,8,...,\cell} {
  \draw[thick,blue!50] (0,\i) -- (\cell,\i);
  \draw[thick,blue!50] (\i,0) -- (\i,\cell);
}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(19-\i)] in {0,...,9}
  \draw[line width=2pt] (\i.1,\i.1) to (\j.9,\i.1) to (\j.9,\j.9) to[bend left] (\i.1,\j.9) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now think about what the curve would look like if the image was over 2.5m wide ...